# Accessing client-side generated table rows through asp.net server-side

Tags: asp.net

The idea is that a pure html table will be generated on the client side. (using jQuery to add dynamic new rows to the table when the user clicks a button).
These rows contain textboxes, dropdownlists, checkboxes and other input controls.

When the user clicks a button, a PostBack is triggered in which I need to access this data from the table on server side, validate it and perform other actions on it.

I'm able to perform the client side and access the table data on server side by adding runat="server" to the table tag. However, I only see the initial table rows (not the ones added through JavaScript) and  I have troubles retrieving the different inputs from the rows.

Can anyone help me out here or put me in the right direction?? Or someone offering a better solution to the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Button1").before("<input name='Input1' type='text' />");
    });
</script>
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input1 = Request["Input1"];
}
```

Comment: @LittleFool Mehdi's answer is correct. I am sorry i posted the wrong answer.voting it to be deleted

Comment: thanks. however i'm talking about rows in a table. this becomes more complex, but I guess I can manage that. Problem is persistence. after post back, the javascript-added rows are gone, so i will have to use some server controls using viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

Im not in front of my dev computer right now but here are my initial thoughts:

You might try using a datagrid to get your table the way you like it. You can then add and manipulate table rows while you're messing with your server side datasource. That would probably be the best solution to what you're trying to do. I would only use jQuery for this if you're using a different language like PHP.

Comment: i don't have a server data source. this is the whole point, they want to add first all rows in a dynamic table and then with 1 post back validate all entries and (if everything is ok, save them further). if not, display validation errors.